# Boolean Algebra and Godel

Tags: boolean-algebra, incompleteness

Can anyone give an example of a theorem in Boolean Algebra that isn't immediately obvious to someone with a computer that can construct a truth table? Clearly no propisition that can be proved using only a truth table can be formally undecidable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is more complicated than computing truth tables, but the first-order theory of Boolean algebras is decidable. This is an old result of Tarski, proved by quantifier elimination. There have been extensions by Rabin, Weese, and others.